# How to change text appearance in a Pandoc lua filter?

Tags: lua, pandoc

I'm using Pandoc to convert my academic paper from markdown to pdf via latex. For the author block I'm using the *scholarly-metadata.lua* filter with a custom filter for the author block.

It currently looks like this:

[Current formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtTBm.png)

I would like to decrease the text-size of the institute name and email, and to display these in italics. Can anyone help me how to do this?

The code of the custom Lua filter I'm currently using:

```
-- file: format-authors.lua
local function squash_author (institutes)
  return function (author)
    local name = setmetatable(author.name, {})
    local institute = institutes[tonumber(author.institute[1])]
    return pandoc.MetaInlines(
      pandoc.List(name)
        .. pandoc.List{pandoc.LineBreak()}
        .. pandoc.List(institute.name)
        .. pandoc.List{pandoc.LineBreak()}
        .. author.email
    )
  end
end

function Meta (m)
  m.author = m.author:map(squash_author(m.institute))
  return m
end
```

YAML code with author info:

```
---
title: Example paper
author:
  - Author name:
      institute: the institute name
      email: authoremail@email.com
---
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've tried using pandoc.RawInLine(), but I'm new to Pandoc and Lua and I can't make it work. I either get a Lua error while exporting with Pandoc, or the text appearance doesn't change.

Comment: you want to modify the latex template instead: see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates